# SpecFlow AfterScenario execute each time with total number of scenarios count

Tags: c#, cucumber, specflow

I have created a base class for taking screenshot for failed test cases in C#. I have used specflow with MSTest for automation testing. However, the problem is when a scenarios fails system runs the below `AfterScenario` method for total numbers of scenario counts. For example, I have 40 scenarios in my current project, let say scenario# 1 is running and after scenarion#1 execution `AfterScenario` method will call but it is calling for 40 times, for each time scenario.

Base class code

```
[Binding]
public abstract class TakeScreenshot : Steps
{
    [AfterScenario]
    public void AfterWebTest()
    {
        if (ScenarioContext.Current["run"]=="0")
        {

            if (ScenarioContext.Current.TestError != null)
            {
                TakeScenarioScreenshot(Tools.driver);
            }
            ScenarioContext.Current["run"] = "1";
        }
    }

    private void TakeScenarioScreenshot(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        try
        {            
            string fileNameBase = string.Format("{0}_{1}",
            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmssFFF") , ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title);

            var artifactDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "testresults");
            if (!Directory.Exists(artifactDirectory))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(artifactDirectory);

            string pageSource = driver.PageSource;
            string sourceFilePath = Path.Combine(artifactDirectory, fileNameBase + "_source.html");
            File.WriteAllText(sourceFilePath, pageSource, Encoding.UTF8);
            ITakesScreenshot takesScreenshot = driver as ITakesScreenshot;

            if (takesScreenshot != null)
            {
                var screenshot = takesScreenshot.GetScreenshot();
                string screenshotFilePath = Path.Combine(artifactDirectory, fileNameBase + "_screenshot.png");
                screenshot.SaveAsFile(screenshotFilePath, ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error while taking screenshot: {0}", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my test class where I am inheriting `TakeScreenshot` class

```
[Binding]
public class CheckTwoNumberAreEqual : TakeScreenshot
{

    [Given(@"Check two numbers are same")]
    public void GivenChecktwonumbersaresame()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(2, 3);
    }
}


[Binding]
public class TestAddNewUser : TakeScreenshot
{

    [Given(@"Add two numbers and check answer")]
    public void GivenAddtwonumbersandcheckanswer()
    {
        int a=2+3;
        Assert.AreEqual(2, a);
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to prevent `AfterScenario` execution for n (scenario count)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hook is called so many times, because you have implemented it on a base class.

Hooks are like Step bindings, which are defined globally. So you defined the AfterScenario Hook so many times how many inherited classes you have.
You need it only once.
See this implementation for your requirement: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/blob/master/SeleniumWebTest/TestApplication.UiTests/Support/Screenshots.cs

Please have a look at the blog post of Gaspar Nagy: http://gasparnagy.com/2015/05/specflow-tips-problems-with-placing-step-definitions-to-base-classes/

Comment: I have tried your solution by hooking up the `AfterScenario` and without base class, it has work perfectly. But I have a question... Initially it didn't work it was still running after scenario method multiple times as I have 'TakeScreenshot` class in base project in which I have after scenario method and my test project is referencing base project dll. Question is why `AfterScenario` was running multiple time in base project? any idea

Answer (score 0):

`AfterScenario` is used for execution after running every scenario. Other [hook attributes](http://specflow.org/documentation/Hooks/) are suited better for your task (perhaps `AfterTestRun`).

Comment: Thanks @Ivan R for your answer, I will have a look but `AfterTestRun` will executing after each feature file and moreover I am taking screenshots for each failed scenarios `if (ScenarioContext.Current.TestError != null)
            {
                TakeScenarioScreenshot(Tools.driver);
            }`